# Flash causes Macbook Air to heat up and fans to spin

Tags: osx-lion, flash, fan, temperature, macbook-air

Any flash application results in a drastic increase in CPU temperature (50C->80C) on my Macbook Air, causing the fans to spin really fast. Is there any solution to this, such as an alternate flash plugin?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know that's common problem on OSX and Flash plugin..

However if you're having that problem while browsing youtube I sugest you enable the HTML5 version by going to http://www.youtube.com/html5 and activating the button..

On other heavy flash websites I don't know a solution.